# asp.net core webapi route constraint regex seems to be ignored in certain circumstances

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core

This application is built on ASP.Net Core (.NET Core 2.1). I'm trying to configure a controller (see `RiskController` below) to support the following via http get:

1. Get by ID (`/api/risk/0000001`) should return a single risk graph
2. Find by name (`/api/risk/some%20company%20name`) should return an array of search results
3. Validate ID (`/api/risk/0000002/validate`) should return a true/false if the id exists

Pretty simple stuff, and this all works when the parameter values are ideally suited to each action. I am using regex to constrain the actions and that helps a lot.

My controller declaration:

```cs
    [Produces( "application/json" )]
    [Route( "api/[controller]" )]
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    public class RiskController : ControllerBase
```

The get by ID action:

```cs
        // GET api/risk/0000001
        [HttpGet( "{riskId:regex(^\\d{{7}}|(SI[[PG]]|JPA|DEM)\\d{{4}})}", Order = 0 )]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get( string riskId ) { ... }
```

The find by name action:

```cs
        // GET api/risk/some%20company%20name
        [HttpGet( "{name:length(2,30)}", Order = 1 )]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Search( string name ) { ... }
```

The validate ID action:

```cs
        // GET api/risk/0000001/validate
        [HttpGet( "{riskId:regex(^\\d{{7}}|(SI[[PG]]|JPA|DEM)\\d{{4}})}/[action]", Order = 2 )]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Validate( string riskId )
```

IDs are always 7 digit strings, or begin with SIP, SIG, JPA or DEM followed by 4 digits (one of e.g.: "0000002", "SIP0003", "SIG0004", "JPA0005" OR "DEM0006").

Now to the case that has me baffled is when a user enters, say a **nine** digit number into the search by name field. The search by name should call the api with `/api/risk/000000019`. And that should be handled by the above *find by name action*. But, the constraint regex on the above *get by ID action* matches the nine digit number for some reason which of course doesn't find a entry. And the user sees an error.
However if the user enters, say a **four** digit number in the the search by name field, the call to `/api/risk/0004` matches to the above *search by name action* and works as it should.

Shouldn't the `\d{7}` part of the constraint on the *get by ID action* regex match exactly 7 digits and no more? `/api/risk/000000019` certainly doesn't match the second half of the regex: `(SI[PG]|JPA|DEM)\d{4}`!

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression here:

```cs
 // GET api/risk/0000001
 [HttpGet( "{riskId:regex(^\\d{{7}}|(SI[[PG]]|JPA|DEM)\\d{{4}})}", Order = 0 )]
```

Merely checks that it "starts with" the expression, consider adding a check for the end of the string.
Consider the difference between following simplified regular expressions:

1. `^\d{7}`
2. `^\d{7}$`

Note `1` will match `0000001`, `0000001234` and `0000001ABC`.

Whilst you are probably after `2` which matches `0000001`.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! That never crossed my mind. BTW, I tried to up-vote, but don't have the rep. Maybe someone with rep can up-vote for me??

Comment: @KenHadden Glad that got it for you - you should still be able to mark as the answer.